# More than one Http.RenderAction() in a single View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, renderaction

As we all know `RenderAction()` is either part of:

- Asp.net MVC 1 Futures or
- Asp.net MVC 2 Beta 2

and allows us to render action result inside another view or partial view.

### Description

1. You have a view with multiple partial views displayed using `RenderAction()` helper.
2. At least two partial views render a `<form>` probably by using `Html.BeginForm()` that postback to original view.
3. Postback **is not** performed via Ajax call
4. Postback data is validated upon form POST.

### Problem

When one of the forms gets posted back the other one renders as **invalid**.

**Has anyone used this pattern and solved it?** We should somehow know which `form` performed postback and only that one should validate its POST data. Others should either ignore validation or perform regular `HttpVerb.Get` action processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a hidden field in the form to indicate which one. Or, have a prefix passed to the partial and appended to each element in the form.

About prefixes. First way is to have two properties, calling Html.RenderPartial("partial", Model.Data1/2.WithPrefix("data1")).

```
public class FormModel
{
   public string Prefix { get; set; }
}

public class FormData
{
   public FormModel Data1 { get; set; }
   public FormModel Data2 { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult HandlePost(FormData data)
{
   if (data.Data1 != null) {} else {}
}
```

Second way is the same but use two action parameters.

```
public ActionResult HandlePost(FormModel data1, FormModel data2)
{
   if (data1 != null) {} else {}
}
```

In the partial view you do

```
<%= Html.TextBox(Model.Prefix + ".FormModelField", Model.FormModelField) %>
```

that is, you set field name with the prefix passed in the model.

Of course you may vary this in details.

Comment: I understand the first part about having a hidden field, but I don't understand the second suggestion. Append to element IDs or where? Can you rephrase it please?

Comment: adding prefixes could possibly mean I have to create my own model binder that would recognise my fields and bind them to action parameters as expected?

Comment: Anyway. I did go the *hidden field* route. It doesn't change my URLs and I could make it as transparent as possible. I've written another extension method `BeginSubForm()` that renders an additional hidden field at the beginning that identifies a particular form that does postbacks.